# org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException , not able to use Oracle DataSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

#Update - I figured out solution, putting answer, but keeping this thread open incase anyone wants to share more insights

I am new to Spring Boot, I have searched this problem here and on other sources before posting, couldn't find solution.
I am trying to read records from Oracle DB, from ItemReader (Batch processing),

Error stack:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobInvokerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'processJob'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processJob' defined in class path resource [com/amitpar/springBootBatch/config/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'processJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderStep1' defined in class path resource [com/amitpar/springBootBatch/config/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'orderStep1' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) [spring-boot-test-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at 
    [ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< ERROR!
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobInvokerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'processJob'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processJob' defined in class path resource [com/amitpar/springBootBatch/config/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'processJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderStep1' defined in class path resource [com/amitpar/springBootBatch/config/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'orderStep1' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processJob' defined in class path resource [com/amitpar/springBootBatch/config/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'processJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderStep1' defined in class path resource [com/amitpar/springBootBatch/config/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'orderStep1' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'processJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderStep1' defined in class path resource [com/amitpar/springBootBatch/config/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'orderStep1' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderStep1' defined in class path resource [com/amitpar/springBootBatch/config/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'orderStep1' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'orderStep1' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
```

below is the setup I made by referring to various guides,

-- application.properties

```
    #Oracle connection
    spring.datasource.username=user
    spring.datasource.password=pass
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:1521/instance
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
    spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

--- OracleConfiguration.java

```
    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    @Component  
    public class OracleConfiguration {
        @NonNull
        private String username;
        @NonNull
        private String password;
        @NonNull
        private String url;
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
        
    
        @Bean(name="DataSource")
        public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
            OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
            dataSource.setUser(username);
            dataSource.setPassword(password);
            dataSource.setURL(url);
            dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
            dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
            return dataSource;
        }
        
    }
```

--Trying to use in Reader.java class

```
    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

--BatchConfig.java

```
@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Bean
public Job processJob() {
    System.out.println("#AMIT, in process job, creating file");
    
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("processJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener())
            .flow(orderStep1())
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step orderStep1() {
    System.out.println("#AMIT, in orderStep1");
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("orderStep1").<SubscriberInfo, SubscriberInfo> chunk(5)
            .reader( new Reader())
            .processor(new Processor())
            .writer( new Writer())
            .build();
}
```

--- Update --
First as I expected, putting ItemReader in same class, buidling using JdbcCursorItemReader in SAME class, wire DataSource in same class, it works
2. Second is, if we need to use in MVC style seperate class, we need to wire jdbcTemplate in actual read() overriden method n not while constructing reader class, jdbcTemplate is somehow instantiated at last by Spring container, spring handles transaction process correctly no matter how many we call read() method, so we dont need to worry about result each time its called

----- Solution 1----

BatchConfig.java

```
@Qualifier("Zandu")
    public DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<SubscriberInfo> itemReader() {
        System.out.println("#AMIT_2 creating jdbc itemwriter bean");
        
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<SubscriberInfo>()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .sql(" select  customer_id, subscriber_no from subscriber  where sys_creation_date > to_date('20200101','YYYYMMDD')  and rownum < 11")
                .rowMapper(new subscriberRowMapper())
                .name("subscriberReader")
                .build();
    }
```

--Solution 2----

BatchConfig.java

```
@Bean
public Reader reader() {
      System.out.println("#AMIT in Batch config create bean reader");
      return new Reader();
}
```

Reader.java

```
public class Reader implements ItemReader<SubscriberInfo>  {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Zandu")
    DataSource dataSourceVar;
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public SubscriberInfo read()
            throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        
        jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSourceVar);
        subscriberInfoList = jdbcTemplate.query(QUERY_FIND_SUBSCRIBER,
                          new subscriberRowMapper());     
        
        System.out.println("#AMIT IN most important read method *********** ");
      
        if(count<subscriberInfoList.size()) {
            System.out.println("Reading count="+count);
            return subscriberInfoList.get(count++);
        }
        else {
            count=0;
        }
        
        return null;
    }
 
}
```

Comment: For some reason, it cannot create the Job bean.

Comment: can you try adding configuration like mentioned in this link, for some reason I believe the values are not properly set for datasource.
https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/configuring-the-oracle-jdbc-drivers-in-a-springboot-project

Comment: @Vignesh_A, I tried given article as well, I used qualifier names to track,  in creation -->     @ Bean(name="Zandu")
    @ Primary,   in usage -->  @ Autowired @ Qualifier("Zandu") public DataSource dataSource;   I see bean named "Zandu" is getting created in log, but it still can't find it in Reader class, getting same exception error

Comment: Update , I even made more debugging , made DataSource and JdbcTemplate both beans, initialized them in BatchConfig, and passed to Reader constructor, thinking if I might load it before ItemReader it will get values, printed order of Initializing, #AMIT Initializing DataSource
#AMIT Initializing JdbcTemplate
#AMIT, in process job, creating file
#AMIT in listner
#AMIT, in orderStep1 , still no luck failed with same error, may be I need to chose different approach write everything in single file

Comment: Maybe name the bean `dataSource` instead of `DataSource`?

Comment: --- ANSWER is --- , 1. First as I expected, putting ItemReader in same class, buidling using JdbcCursorItemReader in SAME class, wire DataSource in same class, it works   2. Second is, if we need to use in MVC style seperate class, we need to wire jdbcTemplate in actual read() overriden method n not while constructing reader class,  jdbcTemplate  is somehow instantiated at last by Spring container, spring handles transaction process correctly no matter how many we call read() method, so we dont need to worry about result each time its called